# how to put a message containing various values in separate text boxes in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, serial-port

I have received a message string from the Arduino and now I want to split the message and put them in separate boxes.

The message is:

> "DevID~first value|$DevEUI~2nd value|$HWEUI~3rd value|$AppKey~4th value|"

The message slpits after every `$` sign. The code is as follows, during runtime it does split the message and the string "value" got the new value every time but all text box contains the same value at present time.

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort Arduino = (SerialPort)sender;

    string indata = Arduino.ReadExisting();
    Debug.WriteLine("Data Received:");
    Debug.Print(indata);

    isConnected = true;
    RxString = RxString + indata;
    int endmarkerPos = RxString.IndexOf('|');
    if(endmarkerPos != -1)
    {
        //now pack everything till endmarker into messageString and delete this part from RxString
        messageString = RxString.Substring(0, RxString.IndexOf('|'));
        Debug.Print(messageString);
        RxString = RxString.Substring(endmarkerPos + 1);
    }

    int startmarkerPos = messageString.IndexOf('$');
    if (startmarkerPos != -1)
    {
        messageString  = messageString.Substring(startmarkerPos +1);
        String command = messageString.Substring(0, messageString.IndexOf('~'));
        String value = messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf('~') + 1);
        Debug.Print("---parsed: command: " + command + "\t value: " + value);
        Debug.Print("the trimmed message is: " + messageString);

        if (string.Compare(command , " DevID" ) == 1)
        {
            //messageString = messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf('~') + 1);

            textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = value));
            //textBox1.Text = value;
            messageString = messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf('~') + 1);
            Debug.Print("1st block");
        }
        if (string.Compare(command, " DevEUI") == 1)
        {
            //messageString = messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf('~') + 1);

            textBox2.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox2.Text = value));
            //textBox1.Text = value;
            messageString = messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf('~') + 1);
            Debug.Print("2nd block");
        }
        if (string.Compare(command, " HWEUI") == 1)
        {
            //messageString = messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf('~') + 1);

            textBox2.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox3.Text = value));
            //textBox1.Text = value;
            messageString = messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf('~') + 1);
            Debug.Print("3rd block");
        }
        if (string.Compare(command, " AppKey") == 1)
        {
            //messageString = messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf('~') + 1);

            textBox2.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.Text = value));
            //textBox1.Text = value;
            messageString = messageString.Substring(messageString.IndexOf('~') + 1);
            Debug.Print("4th block");
        }
```

Comment: Suggest you take this as an opportunity to learn how to use the debugger.  Set a breakpoint on the first line of the method, and see where it's going wrong.

Comment: this is horrible at best.. I would really look into `string.split` function and learn how to split on multiple tokens. this is very hard on the eyes, also start using the debugger.

Comment: just as a tip, it really is helpful (for us and for yourself) to write comments in your code which describe what this line of code is supposed to do or what you think it will do. Sometimes they open up your own eyes and make you realize that you have a mistake in the thought process itself. The code is simply the result of this thought process :) Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

[IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the index of the first occurence of the character. So this is why you get always the same substring!

You should may be use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) to split your string twice:

```
string [] values = meassageString.Split('|').Select(x=>x.Split('~').Last()).ToArray();
```

Explanation:

- The first split returns the different parts that are separated by the `|` pipe character.
- The you select each item from this array and split again each item by the `~` character. The split of one item will result in a small array of 2 subitems, and your value will sit on the last position This one you need to take.

now you can distribute the different values into the appropriate textboxes:

```
textBox2.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox2.Text = values[1]));
```

> during runtime it does split the message and the string "value" got the new value every time

That is not what your code really does. Up to now you you perform your operations once. There is no loop that would repeat the Substring procedures. If you use your debugger you will see it.
As I understood you get the posted string as the entire message from `ReadExisting` in on string. Since you do it once, `command` will have only the value that it gets in this line:

```
String command = messageString.Substring(0, messageString.IndexOf('~'));
```

since you don't change it afterwards only 1 `if` condition can be true! the rest of them is practically useless.